# Prove that $2^{2k-1}+2^{k}+1$ is not divisible by $7$ for any $k$ natural number

Tags: divisibility

I am trying to prove this, but I really can't seem to get anywhere with it.. I tried transforming this into something else, but no transformation yields in any useful expression whatsoever.. As always, I'm searching only for a little hint, just to start going, I dont want a solution posted here. I will post a solution after I get it so that someone else can find it is a full ;) Thanks.

Comment: Multiply by $2$. Subtract $1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could he also try a proof by induction?

Comment: @twirlobite Sure, that works too if keeping the two powers separate.

Comment: What can be said about $2^{k+3}\bmod 7$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel said, double, which does not change the question of divisibility by 7. And $$ x^2 + 2 x + 2 $$ is never divisible by 7 for integer $x.$ So, what is $x?$

Comment: Very nice :). I had the form $(x^{2}+2x+2)$  devided by 2, which created a problem. I completely ignore the fact that multiplying by 2 won't affect the divisibily :)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually say more: The number is not divisible by any prime of the form $4n+3$.

Here is the proof;
Let
$$
x=2^k
$$
Then the expression is
$$
h=x^2/2 + x + 1 = \frac{x^2+2x+2}{2} = \frac{(x+1)^2+1}{2}$$

Now a prime $p$ divides $h$ if and only if $p$ divides $(x+1)^2+1$, only if $-1$ is a quadratic residue of $p$. Since $-1$ is not a quadratic residue of primes of the form $4n + 3$ such  prime cannot divide $h$

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many ways to approach this problem.  Here's a hint for one approach:  What can you say about the smallest possible counterexample $k$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ Note $\, 7\mid 2^{2k-1}+ 2\,2^{k-1}+ 1\,\overset{\rm Lemma}\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ \color{#c00}{{-}1} \equiv \color{#0a0}{n^2}\,\overset{\rm cube}\Rightarrow -1\equiv n^6\, $ contra little Fermat.

**Lemma** $\ \ \ m\mid b^{2k-1} + 2\,b^{k-1} + a\,\ (=:\, c)\ $ implies that $\  \color{#c00}{1-ab}\ $ is a $\rm\color{#0a0}{square}$ mod $m$

**Proof** $\ {\rm mod}\ m\!:\,\ 0\equiv bc = b^{2k} + 2b^k +ab  \equiv (b^k+1)^2 + ab-1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{1-ab} \equiv \color{#0a0}{(b^k+1)^2}$